# How I can take data from all pages?

Tags: python, scrapy, frameworks

it's first time when I'm using Scrapy framework for python.

So I made this code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.emag.ro/televizoare/c'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath('//div[@class="card-section-wrapper js-section-wrapper"]'):
            yield {
                'product-name': i.xpath('.//a[@class="product-title js-product-url"]/text()')
                                .extract_first().replace('\n','')
            }

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="js-change-page"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

when I'm looking at the website it has over 800 products. but my script it's only taking the first 2 pages nearly 200 products...

I tried to use css selector and xpath, both same bug.

Can anyone figure out where is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to crawl is getting data from API. When you click on the pagination link, it sends ajax request to API to fetch more products and show them on the page.

Since

> Scrapy doesn't simulate the browser environment itself.

So one way would be that you

1. Analyse the request in your browser network tab to inspect the endpoint and parameters
2. Build the similar request yourself in scrapy
3. Call that endpoint with appropriate arguments to get the products from the API.

Also you need to extract the next page from the json response you get from the API. Usually there is a key named pagination which contains info related to total pages, next page etc.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out how to do it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import ScraperItem


class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.emag.ro/televizoare/c'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = ScraperItem()

        for i in response.xpath('//div[@class="card-section-wrapper js-section-wrapper"]'):

            product_name = i.xpath('.//a[@class="product-title js-product-url"]/text()').extract_first().replace('\n                        ','').replace('\n                    ','')

            items["product_name"] = product_name

            yield items

            next_page = 'https://www.emag.ro/televizoare/p' + str(SpiderSpider.page_number) + '/c'

            if SpiderSpider.page_number <= 28:
                SpiderSpider.page_number += 1
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```